# A Function Which Returns Parent Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, return, watch

I am having issues with some code. Basically I use jquery to run a callback function upon a button click. My issue is that the entire listening setup is within another function. When the jquery event fires I want to return the parent function, but I can’t figure out how.

Thanks,

-Alex

```
function placeObject(object) {

        $("#button").click( function() { 

            $(".fields").remove()   
            $("#curser" + object).remove()  
            $("#curser" + object).css("pointer-events","none");
            $("#curser" + object).css("display","none")
            $("#submitObject").css("display","none")
            $("#cancelCreation").css("display","none")
            $(".newObjectButton").css("display", "inline")
            zooming = true

        });

}
```

**Update:**

That function is called by this one:

```
function createObject(object) {

    $("#button").css("display","inline")

    if (object == "one thing") {
        placeObject(object)
    }
    else if (object == "another thing") {
        differentFuntion(object)
    }

}
```

That function is called by this:

```
$(".newObjectButton").click( function() {

    createObject($(this).attr("id"))

});
```

In an attempt to clarify my exact goal:

I don't want to have a function return a function like this:

```
funtion a() {
    return b
}
funtion b() {
    alert("b")
}
```

where the result would be an alert box saying "b"

I want the return value of function a to be a signal which returns the encapsulating parent function b like this:

```
function a() {

    function b() {
         return return //whatever value forces the parent function to return
    }

}
```

Comment: So you want to return `parentFunction` from within the `click` event handler? You can do that using `return parentFunction` but it's just going to be returned to the internal jQuery caller.

Comment: I guess that is part of my issue. In context, I am placing a sprite on an image. In order to stop placement, one of two things needs to happen: 1 submitting 2 cancellation. The jQuery event fires when the cancel button is clicked, additionally to that however I want the parent function, that handles either submission or cancelation to return.

Comment: Alright, I think we probably need a little more contextual code, such as the caller of `parentFunction` and perhaps the intended usage of the returned function.

Comment: sounds like an `X-Y` problem. You should start at the beginning explaining what you are trying to achieve in words, not what you want to return from functions

Comment: You guys are right, the question isn't quite clear. I'm sorry. Still, I've been staring at this problem for too long tonight. I'll make a thorough update early tomorrow. I hope you all stick around and continue to be this helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function a(){
 b();
}

function b(){
 console.log(arguments.callee.caller);
};
```

function b will log:

```
function a(){
 b();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions are objects so they can be used as return values. For instance,

```
var setup = function() {
  alert(1);
  return function() {
    alert(2);
  };
};

var my = setup(); // alerts 1
my(); // alerts 2
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the wonderful explanation, but it doesn't accomplish exactly what I mean to do. I will update with more precise wording.